# How to resolve the error of service?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, windows-services, winscp-net

I have a .NET project [scenario] in which I:

1. Downloaded files from WinSCP.com library in .NET
2. Parsed them, created tokens, inserted them into a SQL-DB using LINQ to SQL.

The problem is during converting it into a service. The downloading part goes fine when I run the service, but when pushing into the DB using the LINQ to SQL, it gives an exception without entering even a single row in the database.

Note: the exception found using EventLog is as under:

```
Application: ErrLogsService_57_92.exe 
Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException Stack: at 
System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(System.Data.Linq.ConflictMode) at 
ErrLogsService_57_92.ErrLogsCreation.Read_Log_File(System.String, Int32, Int32) at 
ErrLogsService_57_92.ErrLogsCreation.parseFileAndPush(Int32) at 

System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object) at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

The code inserting the data is:

```
if (CheckLineErrorNot(Line_Str_Is))
{
    sql_DB_LOGS_aDataContext rowInsert = new sql_DB_LOGS_aDataContext();
    Col1 = Get1_Column_DateTime(Line_Str_Is, 0);
    Col2 = Get2_Column_JavaFileName(Line_Str_Is, 59);
    Col3 = Get3_Column_PortNumber(Line_Str_Is, 90);
    Col4 = Get4_Column_ErrorString(Line_Str_Is, endIndexOf_JavaFile, Line_Str_Is.Length);

    // Request creation to insert Error-Logs
    LogsError insertQry = new LogsError
    {
        DateTime = Col1.ToString(),
        FileName = Col2.ToString(),
        PortNumber = Col3.ToString(),
        ErrorString = Col4.ToString(),
        ID_IP = (int)IP,
        ID_FILE = (int)ID_FILE_IS
    };
    rowInsert.LogsErrors.InsertOnSubmit(insertQry);
    rowInsert.SubmitChanges();
}
else
{
    ;
}
```

Comment: How about debugging?

Comment: I have checked, but it gives me an error while inserting.
Please check the EXCEPTION ERROR @Reniuz

Comment: Show the code that creates the token objects and saves them to the database. Also, the `SqlException` will tell you what's wrong. We can't answer this question.

Comment: I am confused. Tell me if we have to reconfigure the LINQ to SQL Connection while shifting from App to Service. @GertArnold

Comment: Well, if you'd show the `SqlException`...

Comment: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: <local machine>] is the ERROR while pushing @GertArnold

Comment: The file is being traversed correctly as well as the tokens too. [confirmed]

Comment: The connection string should be in the application's config file.

Comment: Thanx for your help. I have resloved it. Mine issue was that i was windows authentication to access a local-db [unintentionally]. Horrible mistake. Resolved it using Account-type: LOCAL-SYSTEM. (i was new)